# Inserting div content between thead & tbody

Tags: css

I have a table where I want an input row between the header and body - currently, the existing code implements it by making the 'header' a seperate div not tied to the actual table contents.

Is there a way to use CSS (possibly with javascript if necessary) to insert a div between the table's header and content?

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ Col1                             ║ Col2    ║ Col3   ║ <- thead
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║            <Inserted DIV content>                   ║
║ Value 1                          ║ Value 2 ║ Value3 ║ <- first tbody tr
╚══════════════════════════════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this as it's not valid to have a `<div>` inside a `<table>`. You should consider inserting another `<tbody>` instead.

Comment: Can't you just make a merged cell just on the top of `<tbody>`?

Comment: I'm fine with inserting the div as a tr right after the tbody (or preferably a 2nd tr for the thead, since I want to do this on a table where content is updated automatically by gwt)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
<td id="foo">
```

then using a standard getElementByID javascript call?

Comment: I've not yet tried javascript, trying for a pure CSS approach if there is any way to do so.

Comment: maybe dividing up the table up and using css's nth-child property?  Kinda hacky and a long shot but worth trying